# Triggering Commands from the ViewModel in WPF with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have created a few Custom Controls (NOT UserControls) with bind-able "ClearCommand" ICommand dependency properties. This property will do exactly what it sounds: it will clear all the values from the control (textboxes, etc). I also bind (some) of those same properties to the VM I describe below.

Now I'm stuck trying to trigger the ClearCommand in those controls in the following MVVM scenario:

I've added a few such controls into my View. The View also includes a "Save" button that binds to my ViewModel's `SaveCommand` `DelegateCommand` property.

What I need to happen is that, upon a successful save, the VM should trigger the `ClearCommand` on those controls found in the View.[image]

**UPDATE**

I've added code examples below. I have a few controls that resemble the ExampleCustomControl. Also, just to note, I am open to restructuring some of this if it's completely off.

Example Control snippet:

```
public class ExampleCustomControl : Control {

    public string SearchTextBox { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CustomObject> ResultList { get; set; }

    public ExampleCustomControl() {
        ClearCommand = new DelegateCommand(Clear);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency Property for Datagrid ItemSource.
    /// </summary>
    public static DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem",
        typeof(CustomObject), typeof(ExampleCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(CustomObject)));

    public CustomObject SelectedItem {
        get { return (CustomObject)GetValue(SelectedCustomObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedCustomObjectProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty ClearCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ClearCommand", typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(ExampleCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency Property for resetting the control
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The command that clears the control"), Category("Common Properties")]
    public ICommand ClearCommand {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ClearCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClearCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public void Clear(object o) {
        SearchTextBox = string.Empty;
        SelectedItem = null;
        ResultList = null;
    }
}
```

Example View snippet:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <control:ExampleCustomControl Grid.Row="0"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Selection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ResetButton" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}">
        Save
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Example ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel : WorkspaceTask {
    public TestViewModel() {
        View = new TestView { Model = this };
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save);
    }

    private CustomObject _selection;
    public CustomObject Selection {
        get { return _selection; }
        set {
            _selection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selection");
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
    private void Save(object o) {
        // perform save
        // clear controls
    }
}
```

Comment: Typically, my commands are on my ViewModel.  From the ViewModel, you are able to call `MyCommand.Execute();`.  If that is not how your project is structured, please post some code to clarify.

Comment: As a quick workaround you could set the PropertyChangedCallback in the PropertyMetadata when you register SelectedIOtemProperty and in the callback, have it clear everything you want.  I would however advise having a think about restructuring your setup and putting the clear in the VM along with all the bound properties.

Comment: My issue with having all of the ExampleCustomControl's properties bound to a viewmodel is reuse. I want the search logic/etc sitting in the custom control and I want to be able to reuse the same control in a few different views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said the VM shouldn't know about the view directly in MVVM so it doesn't make sense really that the VM triggers something on your custom control to clear everything.

I would have set the `DataContext` of the custom control to an object that has all the properties you want to clear, which are all each bound (two-way) to your textboxes etc.  Then in the Save() method you can set a new object (which the custom control `DataContext` is bound to) and all the properties will be cleared for you (assuming you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the object).

UPDATED:

As per my comment, see an example of the workaround for your current setup (untested btw):

```
    public static DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem",
        typeof(CustomObject), typeof(ExampleCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(CustomObject), OnSelectedItemChanged));


    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cont = source as ExampleCustomControl;

            //do all the clearing of txtboxes etc here....
        cont.SearchTextBox = string.Empty;
    }
```

But I would still try and move all this into the VM.  i.e. have a clear command, like you do with the save command and bind the textbox text etc to a property in the VM and when the command is called it clears everything, which you can then easily call from the Save method in the VM too.  But obviously I have no idea what you are trying to achieve in the long run or how selectedItem and the textboxes etc are related, so depends (as always) i guess.

Comment: The suggested solution won't work since the SearchTextBox is not statically-typed.

Comment: not if you use the DependencyObject and cast back to your ExampleCustomControl, see my updated answer

Comment: How would I implement the ExampleCustomControl as a View/ViewModel so that I can reuse the control (and the contained search functionality) easily and bind it to the SelectedItem from within my TestViewModel?

Comment: It probably really depends on how you want all these reused controls to work with the main view.  But I would say you would need to set up the VM and view, bind the view to it then simply re-use the control in other views.  You will then need to let TestViewModel know which of the other VM is being used (binding to a new property i guess), so that whenever Save is called it can simply alert the referenced VM.  In short:  hold a reference to the current ExampleCustomControlViewModel from the TestViewModel so you can get access to the Clear method.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Having said all of this (and after getting a better picture of what you are trying to get to) you are probably better off doing it all within the control itself by using the callback i mentioned.  It probably adds too much complexity having to reference VM's from VM's when all it's doing is clearing some properties.  Fine line, but if the control has only this basic functionality then best to keep it as it is.  Hope this hasn't confused matters.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are thinking about this the wrong way. In MVVM the ViewModel should never know anything about the custom controls (hence you are having a problem with this Clear functionality).

Your requirements are a bit vague, but have you considered:

1) If the properties are bound from the VM, can't the Control detect when these are changed?

2) If you really need to call Clear from the XAML layer and want to keep it pure MVVM, then consider something like the Expression Blend SDK's [CallMethodAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723947%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

Comment: Regarding #1: I've considered this scenario. The custom controls contain a search textbox and a datagrid to show the results. All the logic to search is contained within the control implementation itself.   The selected value of the control's datagrid is actually a dependencyproperty that I bind to in my VM. While I can reset the selected value from within my VM, how would I trigger a reset of the rest of the controls in the Custom Control?

Comment: Alex- I think you need to post some cut down sample code in order to get further help. Nothing beats a code sample.

Comment: Let me follow that up by stating that while I could trigger an event from the DependencyProperty, that event will have to be included in a static scope. This doesn't work to reset the control's non-statically scoped properties.

Comment: I see- have you considered using Coerce value callback- that has a reference to the DependencyObject?

Comment: I've updated the question with actual code snippets. As stated, I am open to restructuring it all if it means solving this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to my comment.  I suspect your command is targeting the View and clearing the `TextBox`es directly.  Instead, have your command target the ViewModel and clear the properties the View is bound to.  Then you can have the command be a property on the ViewModel and call it whenever needed.